# php ArgumentCountError when creating a controller as resource

Tags: php, laravel, controller, laravel-artisan

I am starting a project with laravel 9, and when I try to create a controller as resource using `php artisan make:controller Api/UserController --resource --api` I get the following error:

> ArgumentCountError
>
> Too few arguments to function Illuminate\Routing\Router::resource(), 1
> passed in
> /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Facade.php
> on line 353 and at least 2 expected

Is something wrong with the command or is it deprecated? if so, is there any other way to generate the file?

Comment: Just use `--api` and avoid `--resource` if your intention is to create an API Resource Controller. [Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/controllers#api-resource-routes)

Comment: I still get the same error